# Why do iptables rules disappear when restarting my Debian system?

Tags: debian, boot, iptables

I add this rule:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d a.b.c.d -p tcp \
       --dport 1723 -j DNAT --to-destination a.b.c.d:10000
```

1. When restart computer rules are deleted. Why?
2. What I can do to make the rules persist?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There is no option in iptables which will make your rules permanent. But you can use `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` to fulfill your task.

First add the iptable rule using the command you gave.

Then save iptables rules to some file like `/etc/iptables.conf` using following command:

```
$  iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf
```

Add the following command in `/etc/rc.local` to reload the rules in every reboot.

```
$  iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf
```

Comment: On Debian there is the `iptables-persistent` package which will do this.

Comment: It's rather bad idea to place it in `rc.local` since there would be an open window gap between services start and firewall policy apply. I do prefer using `pre-up` *hook for loopback interface* in `/etc/network/interfaces` to overcome this.

Comment: @poige: I agree 100%, `rc.local` might have the intended effect, but it's a kludge in this situation.

Comment: @bahamat: Installing that package is the best solution, It deserves it's own answer.

Comment: @TechZilla: Done.

Comment: did not work for me on Raspbian Jessie ...

Answer (score 93):

On Debian, install `iptables-persistent`:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

The package will automatically load `/etc/iptables/rules` for you during boot.

Any time you modify your rules, run `/sbin/iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules` to save them. You can also add that to the shutdown sequence if you like.

Comment: There are two different rule files: `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` and `/etc/iptables/rules.v6` for IPv4 and IPv6 respectively. If you want a table to apply to both kinds of connections you have to save it to both rule files.

Comment: **Don't add it to your shutdown sequence!** If you botch your rules during changes/setup at least a good old reboot will get things back to the previously working state.

Comment: If you want to save both kinds of rules (IPv4 & IPv6, as described by @PetaspeedBeaver) you need to use the `ip6tables` and `ip6tables-save` command.
So, it's `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4` for IPv4 iptables rules and `ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6` for IPv6 iptables rules.

Answer (score 4):

After installing `iptables-persistent` above you can also save rules with the following shorter command on Ubuntu 16.04+:
`sudo netfilter-persistent save`

And they can also be restored back to how they were last time you saved them with:
`sudo netfilter-persistent reload`

Answer (score 2):

Because you did not save the iptables rules.

You can do that by using `sudo iptables-save`

Comment: That command only shows the rules on the console.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install `iptables-persistent` package
2. Whenever you change the rules of iptables, you should save the backup into  following file using following command:

`iptables-save -f /etc/iptables/rules.v4` (for iptables)

`iptables-save -f /etc/iptables/rules.v6` (for ip6tables)

Answer (score -3):

First install the persist iptables (ubunut or debian)

```
   apt install iptables-persistent
```

Run your statement:

```
   iptables -A INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5433 -j ACCEPT
```

Then save the settings

```
   iptables-save
```

Finally restart the machine to verify

```
reboot
```

Comment: Did not work for me

Comment: duplicate answer of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52522/72456

Comment: `iptables-save` does not save anything. Read the manual: `man iptables-save`.